# iOS NSJSONSerialization returns null when it contains base64 string

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64, nsjsonserialization

My response contains image with base64String.

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;               
id jSon = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:(0) error:&jsonError];
```

Error text is

> "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
>   "

Please help me to parse this data.

If I transform the response I broke image base64String, then I can't load it.

```
NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:(NSUTF8StringEncoding)];  
NSString *str1 = [stringData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];  
NSString *str2 = [str1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];  
NSString *str = [str2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];  
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

jsonError = nil;  
jSon = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
```

Comment: It's rather impossible to answer the question without knowing the `data`. Print the entire `jsonError` object rather than its `localizedDescription` property to get a more meaningful error message. And what is the difference to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169617/ios-how-to-parse-response-that-contains-base64-image-string)?

Comment: {"data":{"result":0, "img":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU.....5ErkJggg=="}}
this is my response. When i try to serialise if gives error.("The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. "). So i have transformed some characters and got  response. Please help me to have serialisation without mutating the data.

Comment: I have sent my response to your email from github. jsonError object is "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unescaped control character around character 124." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 124.}"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the base64 encoded string contains `linefeed` characters which have to be escaped in a JSON string. If you are responsible for the server side send the base64 encoded string without inserting a line feed character after every 64 characters.

Otherwise it's sufficient to remove the linefeed characters

```
NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:(NSUTF8StringEncoding)];  
NSString *str1 = [stringData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];  
NSData *data = [str1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

jsonError = nil;  
jSon = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
```